# How to terminate the batch job of a .bat file an stay in console?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I've recently come back to batch coding. Now, all my code is ready, but I want to add a special feature: a password protected "developer mode".

I've been thinking about `cmd /c ""` but this just exits the window.

I want to insert a code that terminates the current batch job, but then **stays** in the command prompt window so that the user can normally execute commands that may even affect the *.bat* file.

Comment: Read `cmd /?` in an open cmd window -> `cmd /K` and what about  `exit /b` in your batch? See `exit /?` or read about batch commands in [ss64.com](http://ss64.com/nt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call your batch from another batch with `start` it stays up.

runfirst.bat :
`start mybat.bat`

mybat.bat :
`your preexisting code here`

mybat.bat will stay open and you can continue to execute commands in that window.

My exact test:

(Both files saved in C:\temp7)

**runfirst.bat**

```
cd c:\temp7
start mybat.bat
```

**mybat.bat**

```
ipconfig /all
```

The cmd windows stays open to c:/> after being ran.